# Face KPIs using two slicer values

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I am trying to compare Charts and KPIs in PowerBI report. In fact, face the same figures tables but with different slicing values (time room, countries...) 
I could only create two tabs with basically the same slicers and visualization. But I couldn't put them one aside the other that apply to that tab. 
Can anyone help me with this.

Many thanks,

Comment: can you please elaborate on your issue, share some pictures of what you have tried and what you would like to display.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question - is the goal to have a single tab with two KPI visuals - each filtered according to different values? For example, assuming a table with "Sales" and "Countries" columns, create a report with sales KPIs for different countries?

Comment: @G0BLiN, Yes that's exactly what I'm trying to do!

Answer (score 0):

You have several options, here are the simplest two:

## Use *visual level filters* to display two visuals with different filtering

There are three levels to the `Filters` sub-pane - "visual", "page" and "report" - they control the scope of a filter.
When editing a visual, you can drag any data field to the `Filters` sub-pane's "visual" field-well and configure a filter affecting only that visual.

As a simple example: for a table with "Sales" and "Country" columns, you can create one KPI visual showing sales and configure its filter to "UK", then create another KPI (or just copy the first one) and configure its filter to "France" etc. Using this approach you can create several KPI visuals in the same page, each displaying sales data for a different country (Tip: you'll probably want to edit their titles so that viewers can tell which KPI shows what).

## Use *Edit Interactions* to have slicers that affect only some visuals on the page

In Power BI Desktop, go to `Format` tab in the ribbon and click "Edit Interactions". This causes each visual to display several small buttons on its top right corner - these control how the active visual affects each other visual (typically you can select between "highlight", "filter" and "no interactions", note that not all visuals supports all three options).

As a simple example with the same table from above, you can create two KPI visuals showing sales and two slicers filtering by country. Then, edit the interactions so that one slicer affects only one KPI and the other slicer only affects the other KPI. This will create an interactive report with two KPIs comparing sales between any two countries - according to the user's actions on the slicers.

Finally, these posts from MS Power BI have detailed tutorials (including screenshots) for the two options described above:

[Visual level filters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/power-bi-report-add-filter)

[Visual interactions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/service-reports-visual-interactions)